# CSS: submit button - vary width, gradient, rounded corners - no CSS3

Tags: css

I have submit button, which width might vary and it has gradient rounded corners. I am thinking if there are any best practices of writing html + css for it *without* using CSS3 or JS.
 I am thinking on structe like:

```
  <input type='submit' class='buttonLeft' value='Send!' />
  <span class='buttonRight'></span>
```

and css:

```
 .buttonLeft{
      float: left; 
      background: url('button.png');
 }

 .buttonRight{
      width: 20px;
      background: url('button.png') scroll 100% 0%;
 }
```

The visual part will be just fine - the width will be adjusted and it will be displayed nicely. the only problem is that "span" is not clickable - so I will not be able to click on the very last right part of the button. I am thinking if there are any solutions without this flaw? I am aware of JS solutions (including CSSPie for CSS3 in IE) but I would like to avoid it. Any ideas how to use pure css to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the span around the button. In the span, set the background to be the right side sliver of the button (only as wide as you need to accomodate any rounded corners).
See how it was done on this site: http://urbanairship.com/. 
While most of these buttons are anchors, it will work the same for a submit button.